# When a Component/Plugin was updated

Tags: component, plugin, extensions, update

Is there a way to check when a component/plugin was updated?

I have a problem with my Joomla installation and I updated a component/plugin soon, but cannot remember which and when..

Answer (score 2):

There is no such house-keeping info stored in the database - although sometimes I have wished that too. However you should be able to get a clue by checking the creation date of the files/folders via FTP.

An recently updated/installed extension, or recently uploaded/modified files will have a newer file date.